# Serialization of case classes extending Seq-Trait

Tags: json, scala, json4s

It looks like when I try to serialize a case class extending from Seq it gets handeled as a Seq and all additional fields are omitted.

Serializing just leads to a Standard Sequence without the additional fields. Whereas deserialization fails.

Anybody knows what I'am doing wrong here?

Code:

```
// Definition of class
case class IntSeq(count: Int, ints: Seq[Int]) extends Seq[Int] {
    def length: Int = ints.length
    def iterator: Iterator[Int] = ints.iterator
    def apply(idx: Int) = ints(idx)
}
// type Hints
implicit val hints = Serialization.formats( ShortTypeHints(List(classOf[IntSeq])) )

lazy val testIntSeq = IntSeq(5, List(1,2,3,4,5))

val ser = Serialization.write[IntSeq](testIntSeq)
// ser: String = [1,2,3,4,5]

Serialization.read[IntSeq](ser) // Hurray: org.json4s.package$MappingException: unknown error
```

Comment: Probably the JSON4S gives higher priority to sequences than case classes when automatically constructing a format. As @fortran says, it seems rather odd that you extend `Seq` here, but in fact I have used a similar construction myself at some point. I don't know JSON4S, so here are just some guesses: (a) Perhaps you can define a super type which has the same fields but doesn't yet mix in the `Seq` trait, and then define the format for that super type. (b) You might be able to trick JSON4S by using `SeqLike` instead. (c) Manual format. (d) Don't mix in `Seq` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Without discussing why such a class is useful... How would you manually encode such object?

In JSON you can have dictionaries and lists, so you cannot expect a list to have extra named attributes.

You can make your `IntSeq` class to have a list attribute and not extend `Seq` itself (and maybe provide an automatic conversion), so your JSON could look like:

```
{'length' : 5, 'ints' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The real usage is quite different but the simplified example convoys the problem: I dont't want to loose the additional information I provided without giving up using the class like an Sequence. Is there any way to accomplish serialization without loosing the additional information. The implicit conversion would also ommit the additional value.